# Angular vs AngularDart performance?

Tags: angular, performance, angular-dart

Considering the latest versions of `Angular` and `AngularDart`, is there any significant performance difference between the 2 frameworks?

Also, what are the pros and cons of either over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've done a lot of work in AngularDart to make it fast. It powers some of Google's most important apps. For details see https://news.dartlang.org/2016/03/the-new-adwords-ui-uses-dart-we-asked.html and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0a0iZW4RZXg&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIIJr3vjxggY7yGcGO7i9BK5

Obviously, you'll have to opt into using the Dart language and tools to use AngularDart.

Comment: But how is it different from Angular 4/5, except for the language and syntactical changes. I have been reading up on AngularDart, but could not get a comparison between the TS version and Dart version of angular anywhere.

Answer (score -4):

AngularDart is SDK and the base codes are different from core angular.